# How do we parse JSON in Unity3d?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, json.net

When I try to use JsonUtility to parse the JSON from a REST call returning an array of elements, it fails saying that top level must be an object. C'mon guys. That's ridiculous.

OK, moving on to figuring out how to use Newtonsoft.json because it works well everywhere else.

Tried using JSON .NET for Unity out of the asset store. Seemed like it would work fine and did in the editor, but didn't work (calls to it failed with exceptions) when I tried to use it in a Mac local build on my dev macbook pro. So if it doesn't work on my dev machine and for mac builds, then it's a no go. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347

Tried using jilleJr's version from here: https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity but the installation instructions caused the package manager to not be able to open. I get a null reference exception when following the directions to add the package directly into my manifest.json

So what's the secret to making JSON work in Unity 2019/2020 right now? Seems like a huge problem for a platform to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `*YourUnityProject*/Packages/manifest.json` and add the following line to the *dependencies* object.

```
"com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json": "2.0.0",
```

To serialize and deserialize data use these functions:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Data
{
    int[] numbers;
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Data());
Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

Comment: I saw that Unity added in support for JSON.net. Very wise. Can you just add the using statement "using Newtonsoft.Json" into your code snippet above the class declaration, and I think everyone will understand it so I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Also, do you know if that happens to work in Unity 2019 too or is it just 2020? I would think that because it's a nuget package that it would work fine in 2019 as well.

Comment: @Brian Not sure about 2019, I use 2020 exclusively.

Comment: OK, good enough for now. We're using 2020 ourselves. Was just wondering. Marking as answer. Thank you very much for your help. We've tried it and it's working well.

Comment: We did have a related question about how we can use com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json when using photon networking. So, we're not quite out of the woods yet, but I think this answer about using Unity's newtonsoft package is good for now. The issue about conflicts with Photon are in this other stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957972/can-we-use-unitys-newtonsoft-json-package-when-using-photon

Comment: OK, the photon issue was a total red herring. Not related to JSON at all. @Iggy, thank you very much for your answer. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a problem with Unity, back when I was trying to read data in from serialised JSON. `JsonUtility` worked a treat when serialising/deserialising to/from a class. I also preferred it to Newtonsoft.json, mainly because it was part of `UnityEngine`

For example:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class JSONRW : MonoBehaviour
{
    PersonData data;
    string jsonPath = "Assets/TestJSON.json";

    private void Start()
    {
        //Read in JSON file
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
        data = JsonUtility.FromJson<PersonData>(jsonString);

        Debug.Log(data.client[0].name); //Outputs A

        //Write to JSON file
        data.client[0].name = "Luc"; //Changes the name of the entry named A
        File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, JsonUtility.ToJson(data)); //Writes updata back to file
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public Person(string _name, int _age)
    {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class PersonData
{
    public List<Person> client;
}
```

JSON file:

```json
{
  "client": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "B",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "C",
      "age": 30
    },
    {
      "name": "D",
      "age": 40
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've used JsonUtility and it was OK for some simple things, but we quickly ran into problems. Doesn't support top level arrays and also doesn't support DateTime elements. I didn't go much farther with it because we specifically work with lists of data that are the results of queries and we have lots of DateTime information.

Comment: I haven't had any problems with JsonUtility storing DateTime data, I'm not at my computer right now but I might be able to show an example later. For top level arrays I'm not sure, but I can't see why it wouldn't work

Comment: Definitely doesn't work with top level arrays. There are posts about it. It might be that our DateTime elements were nullable, but it was having trouble with that and I had to treat them as strings.

Comment: Hi Luc, I followed up on the datetime issue. We found that when we posted an object to the server that contained a DateTime field actually a nullable "DateTime?" that JsonUtility.ToJson didn't actually put it in the object to send to the server and we received nulls on the server side. We changed the data type of the field to be string and serialized the field into standard ISO format using myDatetime.ToString("o") and sent the strings to the server and then that was OK.

Comment: Instead of changing `DateTime?` to a string, you could instead send an invalid DateTime for example `new DateTime(0000, 00, 00);` which may be simpler to interpret in the future, instead of converting between `DateTime` and strings

Comment: I don't know if it was a problem because it was nullable or not. Might have been. On the server side it handled it fine though if I used ISO string format for correct dates and null. That's the way all of our standard APIs work.