# How to read data from json file?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to read text from json file by numbers? Each line in the file has a key assigned to it, "1", "2", "3", etc.

```json
{
   "1": "Hello",
   "2": "Can I help you?",
   "3": "We'll figure it out ourselves.",
   "4": "",
   "5": "",
   "6": "",
   "7": ""
}
```

Comment: If you can use C++, try `json` or `jsoncpp` - there are many other JSON parsers

Comment: No, sorry, but I can only use C #. And I have already tried some methods, but they do not work with keys "1", "2", etc.

Comment: [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) is built in to Unity.  You can deserialize your json into a Dictionary<int, string>.

Comment: @hijinxbassist the [Unity Serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#FieldSerliaized1) which is used by `JsonUtility` doesn't support `Dictionary` -> @OP you will need to use a third party library such as e.g. `Newtonsoft JSON.Net` (comes as a semi built-in [Package via the PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html)) and then checkout [Newtonsoft JSON -> Deserialize `Dictionary`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)

Comment: However .. why not simply use a) a plain file where each new line is a new item instead of JSON at all or b) instead of keys simply an array of strings -> an array already is indexed anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we parse JSON in Unity3d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955593/how-do-we-parse-json-in-unity3d)